# MATLAB fmincon interior-point Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to run `fmincon` function of MATLAB optimization toolbox in the following form:

```
   fmincon(@fun,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

I cannot find a solution , getting

> No feasible solution found.

I went for troubleshooting by testing boundaries with the following code:

```
   f = zeros(size(x0));
   xnew = linprog(f,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

This did not work but when I did `Aeq=sparse(Aeq);A=sparse(A);` magically it did! But sparse does not work for `fmincon`!

In addition to that, I get this Warning:

> Matrix is singular to working precision

when I run `fmincon`. I think this matrix is a matrix in the `fmincon` function. But still I presume the problem is about my matrices because of the sparse experience above. Here is an example of my matrices:

```
   A =0.3333   -0.3333     Aeq = 1     1
      0.6667    0.3333
      0.3333    0.6667
```

So do you have any idea what is the problem and how I can solve it?

By the way my linear problem can only be solved with 'active-set' algorithm out of four possible algos with `fmincon`. But this one does not strictly abide to the constraints, giving constraint violated results sometimes.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on that error, it seems like the feasible region is empty. Are you sure your constraints are correct?

Comment: Does it help if you don't use `Aeq`, but specify a lower bound and upper bound (`lb` and `ub`) that allow for a tiny margin of error? Given your matrix I would guess that rounding issues may cause your problem not to have a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. With active set algorithm i have a solution. Plus i tried the region with linprog with a dummy obj fun. So its not the infeasibility.

Comment: Dennis, i will try that. Thanks for the clue.